# Prove $f'(0) = 0$ if $f$ is even

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f$ be an even function on the reals.  Prove $f'(0)$ is either $0$ or undefined.

Intuitively, $f(0) + h\cdot f'(0) \approx f(h) = f(-h) \approx f(0) - h \cdot f'(0) $ for small $h$.  If $h \neq 0$, $f'(0)$ must be $0$.  However, I'm having trouble formalizing this proof.

I believe my difficulty is that there are multiple pairs of $\epsilon, \delta$ needed to be tracked separately, as the derivative is defined as a limit (one epsilon-delta pair), we need to show $f(0) + h\cdot f'(0) \approx f(h)$ (another epsilon-delta pair), and we need to de these for negative $h$ as well (two more epsilon delta pairs).

Can you help me formalize my intuitive argument into a proper, clear, well organized proof?

Comment: If the derivative is undefined, ok. If it is defined, then look at the definition, and observe what you get when you approach with positive $h$, and when you approach with negative $h$.

Comment: @Jonah That's exactly the intuitive argument I cite.  I'm struggling to turn that into something formal.  "Observe what you get" is no more rigorous than the $f(0) + h \cdot f'(0) \approx f(0) - h \cdot f'(0)$ I cite.

Comment: @SRobertJames, Hello, if you want a proper proof, I think my answer below provides what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If $f'(0)$ is undefined, then we are done.

Let us assume that $f'(0)$ is defined. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}-f'(0)\right|<\epsilon,~~~~0<|h|<\delta.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
2|f'(0)|&=\left|\dfrac{f(\delta/2)-f(0)}{\delta/2}-f'(0)-\dfrac{f(\delta/2)-f(0)}{\delta/2}-f'(0)\right|\\
&=\left|\dfrac{f(\delta/2)-f(0)}{\delta/2}-f'(0)+\dfrac{f(-\delta/2)-f(0)}{-\delta/2}-f'(0)\right|\\
&\leq\left|\dfrac{f(\delta/2)-f(0)}{\delta/2}-f'(0)\right|+\left|\dfrac{f(-\delta/2)-f(0)}{-\delta/2}-f'(0)\right|\\
&<\epsilon+\epsilon\\
&=2\epsilon,
\end{align*}
so $|f'(0)|<\epsilon$ is true for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $ f'(0) $ exists.
then
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=$$

$$\lim_{-x\to 0}\frac{f(-x)-f(0)}{-x-0}=$$
$$-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=-f'(0)$$
thus

$$f'(0)=0$$
**remark**

If $ f $ is differentiable around zero then
the differentiation of $$f(x)=f(-x)$$
gives
$$f'(x)=-f'(-x)$$
and
$$f'(0)=-f'(0)$$

Comment: To the proposer:  The remark is an instance of the chain rule $(\,f(g(x))\,)'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) $ with $g(x)=-x.$

Answer (score 0):

$2f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}+\frac {f(0)-f(-x)}{0-(-x)}=$

$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {f(x)-f(-x)}{x}=$ $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac {0}{x}=0.$

Comment: Why $\lim x \to 0^+$ (from the right) and not just $\lim x \to 0$ (from both directions)?

Comment: @SRobertJames .  That works too. Very good.